# CXF version 3.1.4 -- wish to send non-URL encoded href for MTOM attachment

Tags: cxf, mtom

The IRS ACA web service that we access with our Java client has a requirement that we not send % symbol, so not URL encoded, in the href portion of the include and Content-ID. This is automatically being done, by good reason, by Apache CXF but we'd like to send the SOAP request like this:

```
<soap:Body>
  <ns2:ACABulkRequestTransmitter version="1.0" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter" xmlns:ns3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns6="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:ns7="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns8="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader">
     <BulkExchangeFile>
        <xop:Include href="cid:129aa5d3-1815-49b8-847e-b9e51c0cd650-1@urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
     </BulkExchangeFile>
  </ns2:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
```

Again if we send like this

```
129aa5d3-1815-49b8-847e-b9e51c0cd650-1@urn%3Aus%3Agov%3Atreasury%3Airs%3Acommon
```

the IRS won't accept it the request. Any ideas how to remove this URL encoding in Apache CXF?

***EDIT What I did to get this to work with IRS expectations***

Turns out you can leave the href and Content-ID URL encoded. Here's what I did to get the request to work.

I edited src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/attachment/AttachmentSerializer.java
so that it outputs what the IRS expects

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <6920edd2-a3c7-463b-b336-323a422041d4-1@blahurn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common>
Content-Disposition: attachment;name="1094B_Request_BBBBB_20151019T121002000Z.xml"
```

CXF was making the Content-Transfer-Encoding binary and the Content-Type application/octet-stream